# Shadow in separate view from UIImage for dynamic adjustments

Tags: ios, path, uiimageview, dropshadow

I would like to obtain this effect (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023271/how-to-adjust-drop-shadow-dynamically-during-an-uiimageview-rotation) but from a more complex image than just a red square ! If the link ever gets broken, it's a about how to adjust drop shadow dynamically during an UIImageView rotation.

So I tried implementing something but I just can't get the shadow in a separate layer... Here is my code, very simple, but doesn't work:

```
    // here is my code

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"handNoShadow.png"]];

testViewShadow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:testView.frame];

testViewShadow.layer.shadowPath = [[testView layer] shadowPath];
testViewShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
testViewShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
testViewShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;


[self.view addSubview:testViewShadow];
[self.view addSubview:testView];

}
```

PS: i did #import

I do get an image but no shadow... =(

Any lead, help, code, link... is welcome !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

possible cause:

- your testViewShadow.clipToBounds property is set to YES (should be NO)
- your testViewShadow do the drawing of the shadow correctly but another UIView is on top and mask it. Check your Z order. Either the order in Storyboard/Nib file (or the order you added the subviews programmatically). Last in the list (or last one added) is on top. For my app I had to put the UIView that need a shadow last so that no other view mask it.

Comment: none of these seem to be the cause. 
- I think clipToBounds is NO by default and I do not change it (see code).
- I add the views programmatically (see code) and I don't think one should be masking the other here.